# Javascript wont executed in my html Django code

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a very basic HTML code that I include in my Django project, however the JavaScript wont load somehow in my project, the button seems do nothing, where I want to start my guidetour js.

The code is attached below

```
{% load static %}
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Tourguide Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LikaloLLC/tourguide.js@0.2.0/tourguide.css"/>
    <script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
    <script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/LikaloLLC/tourguide.js@0.2.0/tourguide.min.js"/></script>
    <script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"/></script>
    <script src = "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"/></script>
    <script src = "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"/></script>
  </head>

  <body> 
  <h1 style="text-align:center;"> Tour Guide Demo.</h1>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="py-5 text-center">
      <h2>Checkout form</h2>
      <p class="lead">Below is an example usage of Tour Guide content based approach. Click [Start tour] button below to start the guided tour:</p>
      <p>
        <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" id="tourbutton">
          Start tour
        </button>
      

      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 order-md-2 mb-4">
        <h4 class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
          <span class="text-muted">Your cart</span>
          <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill">3</span>
        </h4>
        <ul class="list-group mb-3" data-tour="step: 1; title: Your cart; content: Example cart description text displays cart description">
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
            <div>
              <h6 class="my-0">Product name</h6>
              <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
            </div>
            <span class="text-muted">$12</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
            <div>
              <h6 class="my-0">Second product</h6>
              <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
            </div>
            <span class="text-muted">$8</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between lh-condensed">
            <div>
              <h6 class="my-0">Third item</h6>
              <small class="text-muted">Brief description</small>
            </div>
            <span class="text-muted">$5</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between bg-light">
            <div class="text-success">
              <h6 class="my-0">Promo code</h6>
              <small>EXAMPLECODE</small>
            </div>
            <span class="text-success">-$5</span>
          </li>
          <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between">
            <span>Total (USD)</span>
            <strong>$20</strong>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <form class="card p-2" data-tour="step: 2; title: Promo code; content: Example cart promo code text displays promo code description">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Promo code">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Redeem</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 order-md-1">
        <h4 class="mb-3">Billing address</h4>
        <form class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="row" data-tour="step: 3; title: Customer name; content: Example cart customer name text displays customer name description">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="firstName">First name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" placeholder="" value="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid first name is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="lastName">Last name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Valid last name is required.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12">
              <p>
                <b>Example:</b> tour step describing the two fields abowe is added usigng the following html:
                <code>
                &lt;div class="row" data-tour="step: 3; title: Customer name; content: Example cart customer name text displays customer name description"&gt;
                </code>
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <div class="input-group">
              <div class="input-group-prepend">
                <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
              </div>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback" style="width: 100%;">
                Your username is required.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="email">Email <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="you@example.com">
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter a valid email address for shipping updates.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="address">Address</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="1234 Main St" required>
            <div class="invalid-feedback">
              Please enter your shipping address.
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="address2">Address 2 <span class="text-muted">(Optional)</span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address2" placeholder="Apartment or suite">
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-5 mb-3">
              <label for="country">Country</label>
              <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="country" required>
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option>United States</option>
              </select>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please select a valid country.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
              <label for="state">State</label>
              <select class="custom-select d-block w-100" id="state" required>
                <option value="">Choose...</option>
                <option>California</option>
              </select>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Please provide a valid state.
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
              <label for="zip">Zip</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="zip" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Zip code required.
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="mb-4">
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="same-address">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="same-address">Shipping address is the same as my billing address</label>
          </div>
          <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="save-info">
            <label class="custom-control-label" for="save-info">Save this information for next time</label>
          </div>
          <hr class="mb-4">

          <h4 class="mb-3">Payment</h4>

          <div class="d-block my-3" data-tour="step: 4; title: Payment; content: Example cart Payment text displays Payment description">
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="credit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" checked required>
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="credit">Credit card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="debit" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="debit">Debit card</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
              <input id="paypal" name="paymentMethod" type="radio" class="custom-control-input" required>
              <label class="custom-control-label" for="paypal">PayPal</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="cc-name">Name on card</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-name" placeholder="" required>
              <small class="text-muted">Full name as displayed on card</small>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Name on card is required
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
              <label for="cc-number">Credit card number</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-number" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Credit card number is required
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
              <label for="cc-expiration">Expiration</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-expiration" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Expiration date required
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
              <label for="cc-cvv">CVV</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cc-cvv" placeholder="" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">
                Security code required
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr class="mb-4">
          <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit" data-tour="step: 5; title: Continue; content: Example cart continue button text displays continue button description">Continue to checkout</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

The script.js is include in my {static} / folder which is already loaded.
///

```
    window.onload = () => {
    
var tourguide = new Tourguide();
    function startTour() {
    tourguide.start();
    }
// Attach the touruide start evene to the button press
var tourbutton = document.getElementById("tourbutton");
tourbutton.addEventListener("click", startTour);
}
// Attach the touruide start evene to the button press
```

However the button seems not responsive when I pressed it.

Below is the example output when successfully performed.
[image: Example output]

Comment: What do you mean fail to activate? You can print out the `tourbutton` variable after the `document.getElementById()` line to verify that the JS code found the `tourbutton` btn element

Comment: The tourbutton did nothing when i pressed on it.

Comment: Why are you writing the script tag in the script.js file?

Comment: I have changed it, but the button seems no respond when i pressed on it.

Comment: Is the `tourbutton` variable undefined? Print it out

Comment: Is that all of the `script.js` file? It should listen for the document to be loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First of all put your JS code in the static file in the wrapper function which will lounch your code after all things are loaded:

```
window.onload = () => {
    // your js code here
})
```

Secondly you have to change the way you attach your JS file to the HTML page:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
```

Finally you are trying to get your button like this:

```
var tourbutton = document.getElementById("tourbutton");
```

But your button **does not** have any ID given.

Hopes that will help.

Answer (score 0):

All of your script files are wrapped in stylesheet links. They should instead be wrapped in script src.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/script.js' %}"></script>
```